# Angular directive function param camel case not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular 1.5.8 directive with isolated scope and two functions being passed in.  I have found that when the names of these functions are all lower case that they work correctly but if they are camelCased then they do not work.

Note that I am talking about the value of the param not the param name itself.  here's the html that uses the directive:

```
<buttons-radio model="contactInformationAcceptable" disabled="approved" callback="personalapprovalfieldchanged()" focus="focuscallback($event)"></buttons-radio>
```

Note the case of the callback and focus values.  If I change these to camel case (and change the function definitions in the parent scope) then they don't work.

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module("manageApp").directive('buttonsRadio', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            model: '=',
            disabled: '=',
            callback: '&',
            focus: '&'
        },
        template: '<div class="form-group yesorno"> ' +
            '   <div class="col-xs-12">' +
            '      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{active: yesValue}" ng-click="clickYes()" ng-focus="localFocus($event)">Yes</button>' +
            '      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-disabled="disabled" ng-class="{active: noValue}" ng-click="clickNo()" ng-focus="localFocus($event)">No</button>' +
            '   </div>' +
            '</div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.$watch('model', function (value) {
                if (value) {
                    if (value == 0) {
                        $scope.yesValue = false;
                        $scope.noValue = false;
                    }
                    if (value == 1) {
                        $scope.yesValue = true;
                        $scope.noValue = false;
                    }
                    if (value == 2) {
                        $scope.yesValue = false;
                        $scope.noValue = true;
                    }
                }
            });
            $scope.localFocus = function ($event) {
                $scope.focus({ $event: $event });
            }
            $scope.performCallback = function () {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.callback();
                });
            }
            $scope.yesValue = false;
            $scope.noValue = false;
            $scope.clickYes = function () {
                $scope.yesValue = !$scope.yesValue;
                if ($scope.yesValue) {
                    $scope.noValue = false;
                    $scope.model = 1;
                } else {
                    $scope.model = 0;
                }
                $scope.performCallback();
            }
            $scope.clickNo = function () {
                $scope.noValue = !$scope.noValue;
                if ($scope.noValue) {
                    $scope.yesValue = false;
                    $scope.model = 2;
                } else {
                    $scope.model = 0;
                }
                $scope.performCallback();
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Edit: Here is the parent controller that has the function I need to use:

```
angular.module("manageApp").controller('approvalPersonalController', ['$scope', '$http',
function ($scope, $http) {

    //personalApprovalFieldChanged    personalapprovalfieldchanged
    $scope.personalapprovalfieldchanged = function () {
        //a field has changed so save them all
        console.log('field has changed - do something');
    };

}]);
```

I am confused as to why this is as I have been through a Pluralsight course on directives and the camel case works OK in the plunks that I have created from the course but not in this real world example.

It does work (calls the correct functions at the correct times) but I would like to use camel case for the function names if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Where are those callback functions defined? Which controller? Maybe they are lowercased there as well?

Comment: We need to see the controller to be able to understand ..